# How do I adjust my email notification configuration and policy?

Tags: support, email-notification

I'm a newcomer in the family of sites and I have somewhat trouble finding the mail notification policy or controls for it. Searching around, I've come accross some threads but it seems that I've not read/found the ones outlining the current way to accomplish that.

Under "Edit profile and settings" I've found a "Question subscriptions" option, but it is empty (I expected the two topics I've opened to be there).

Thanks in advance for any information provided.

Comment: There is an "email settings" button in that edit screen, on the left. See [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!