# Why are there Stack Overflow references in profile settings on all community sites?

Tags: discussion, support

There are references to Stack Overflow in the profile settings across *all* community sites. As I understand it, Stack Exchange is the parent company. So shouldn't this be saying Stack Exchange?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Hey PasWei! This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906/282094) some of the email settings (sender's address) are Stack Overflow only,  and some of the settings allow email to be generated for changes in all communities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.co/) is the brand name of the company, Stack Exchange is the Q&A network of sites.

So you might get promotional email from other parts of the Stack Overflow company if you check the box.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) lists Stack Exchange, Inc. as parent company for Stack Overflow as well as the Stack Exchange network. So they are Stack Exchange as a company but refer to themselves as Stack Overflow?

Comment: They changed from SO to SE then back to SO.

Comment: After reading the SO [ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) I think Wikipedia is right. Apparently Stack Exchange, Inc is the operator, but their branding is now Stack Overflow. The changing back and forth between SO and SE probably added to my confusion. Thanks for getting me up to speed.

Comment: Tldr: SE's corporate identity is messy. It started as SO, became SE, then SE did business as SO....

Comment: Yep, what @JourneymanGeek said. Stack Overflow (in addition to being the name of a site) is a business name for Stack Exchange, Inc. (that is, Stack Exchange Inc. does business as Stack Overflow). *Nothing confusing about it at all...* :P