# Email notifications

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instant e-mail notifications of answers to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions)

I am just not sure how does it work? I want it to send me an email notification whenever somebody replies to my question or adds any comments, instantly. But I don't get it right away. Instead of that I get one summary email second day that following questions have some aded comments.

How can I change it?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. The people who run these sites don't like sending frequent e-mails.