# How to get an email when I receive an answer?

Tags: support, email, email-notification

Is it possible to configure my account in Stack Overflow so that I would receive an email when my question is answered?

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91312/email-notification-for-questions

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions

Answer (score 2):

If you hang around for just a little bit longer you *won't need* an email notification :P  On the popular tags, [php](/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), etc...answers are given within **seconds** of posting...  Gone are the days when one would post a question online and only go back a few days later to check if someone has answered.  We have a **very active** community that cruises the question lists looking for stuff to answer.

<s>Other than that I do not believe that this functionality exists.</s>

If you'd like a work around you could simply subscribe to the RSS feed for the question (link is at the bottom of the page) and set up an [RSS to Email](https://www.google.com/search?q=rss+to+email) service so that you get an email for every update to the RSS feed.

[image]

<sub><sub><sub>Not enough jQuery you say?  try this - `window.open($("a:contains('question feed')").attr('href'));`</sub></sub></sub>