# Can you add optional desktop notifications for new inbox items?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, desktop-notifications

I'm getting real tired of noticing new answers or comments to my questions hours after they were posted because I minimize StackOverflow and resumed working. According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions)'s answers you're never going to implement instant email notifications, so could you *at least* give me a sound notification or desktop notification when new inbox items appear? You can even make it optional! Everybody wins.

This would literally just take a few minutes of coding to implement. You already have the events in place, and you've already set up desktop notifications for chat. Come to think of it, I could probably write a Tampermonkey script for this.

My point still stands though. Please consider this.

Comment: "I could probably write a Tampermonkey script for this." - Go right ahead and post it on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)! (There might already be something similar there though.)

Comment: [Chime](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chime/lkdfkbkkfdhhfnhgbphecddnpfnoedke?hl=en) is a good extension that does this. Downside: Marks everything as read when it checks the inbox.

Comment: The link is broken @Manishearth