# My Stack Overflow email profile is set on 3 hours, but I'm not getting any notifications

Tags: support, notifications, email-notification

I'm not getting notified of replies to my posts.

Why?  What setting on stackexchange.com am I missing?

If there's an FAQ for that site, please let me know where, since I can't find one.

Comment: This site is referenced for email issues on the Stackexchange.com web site. One just has to attempt to use the email tag on a new question to read that this site is to be used for email issues.

Comment: Most likely because you're manually checking your inbox, in that case SE won't send email. It's also mentioned, with more details, in [this other answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310813/email-notifications-on-qa-i-have-been-involved-in/310816#310816).

Comment: I hit this site stackexchange rarely. I post a question and then wait, sometimes for a day or more and then check back to see that people have replied but I never got notified. This has gone on for years. I NEVER get notified of replies, no matter how long I wait, except for the email I just got that prompted me to reply.

Comment: Another option, your email is wrong or having typo. When you go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current), double check the email in the textbox is correct. Option #3, check your email spam folder, sometimes email providers are too eagerly marking things as spam, so worth checking if it is there.

Comment: email is correct, Tips & Reminders is ON, InBox is 3hrs, Community Milestones is ON . I'm getting your emails, so why am I not getting them from replies to my posts on the plain stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm not working for SE, and out of ideas. Let's hope someone who does work for SE comes over and will be able to help.

Comment: There were three inbox emails generated over the past couple of days and all three show they were delivered and opened on your end. Unfortunately we can only see data from the past 30 days so cannot investigate further than that. Are you receiving the emails or are they ending up in a filter somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I got several emails initiated from this exchange. I was wondering how these were working and not from stackexchange.com . Here's a recent exchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73514987/2-dimensional-list-referenced-with-3-dimensions-and-it-works-somehow-why Please leave a reply and I'll wait till tomorrow or longer to check that thread.

Comment: You were actively engaging with that question. They did generated inbox notifications, but as others explained emails are only sent when you have *unread* notifications. If you already saw them, there's no point in sending an email. I'm not seeing anything wrong here.