# Please send email notifications immediately when someone answers questions

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

Some time ago, I noticed that Stack Exchange isn't sending email notifications immediately when someone replies to my questions. I'd like to be notified via e-mail when someone answers my questions as soon as possible.

I'm aware that I can [adjust my e-mail settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) to notify me within 3 hours, but I'd like for the notification to be even quicker than that.

Comment: Right now, you can set it for [as low as 3 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1gjA.png). Double-check your settings [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current).

Comment: @41686d6564 I feel that the 3 hours are too long. I hope it can as soon as possible.

Comment: FYI, [this has been requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6557/348196) (and [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31596/348196)) over 12 years ago. I'm intentionally not voting to close as duplicate though because a lot has changed in the past 12 years and this feature request might have merit now.

Comment: SE used to have a perfectly functioning tool for instant notifications, pity they killed off the apps :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, I loved that app very much.

Comment: As an alternative you can use a page tracker [like this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/distill-web-monitor-ff/) and track your question to see if anyone answers.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Thanks. I never thought about this good things,