# would be great to have "my RSS channel"

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RSS feed for my “Recent Activity” page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page)

Would be great to have an RSS channel with all questions asked by me and all comments/replies to them.

Having this in place I can ask a question and close the site, since I have RSS channel in Vienna (or any other RSS reader). As soon as I get an answer or comment to my question - I get a message in the RSS reader, click it and go to the site to read it.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page

Comment: Sounds like a great way to not bother coming back to the site.

Comment: @Shog9 But that is the devils question.

Comment: @Yacoby: the feature-request-of-the-beast