# existing question has no answer - what can I do?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

there are few questions related to [RSS feed for my “Recent Activity”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page) but I couldn't find any answer. It seems to me that nothing is going to happen.

What can I do in that case? I added some comments to existing question but it had no effect. I cannot create new question on that topic as it would be duplicate. So I have to accept that nothing will happen? Or is there anything that could be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something we expect the availability of the API to solve, at least partially.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/

Comment: ...I partly copied this to [the actual question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page).

Comment: I hope there will be ruby wrapper to the API soon :-)

Comment: How the API would solve that problem exactly?

Comment: I would create my own RSS out of it or I would send an email to myself or what ever else.....

Answer (score 1):

At least for the question,

The recent activity page is a protected page. You cannot access any other user's recent activity page, and no one can access yours. While there really isn't much in the way of private information display on the page, the page is still only viewable to a person logged into that specific account.

In order for an RSS feed to be create for this page, it would require cookie checking and/or a pass-code given in the URL. I don't believe the developers are ready to implement something like that, so you won't be able to turn the Recent Activity page into an RSS feed without using some 3rd party methodology.

Comment: I assume this was true in 2010, but nowadays anyone can see it, and anyone can use the "user feed" (linked in the bottom right corner of the "info" tab, sub-tab "stats") [of anyone they like](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/84237). So: no authentication required at all.