# Feature request: personalized RSS Feeds

Tags: feature-request, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RSS feed for my “Recent Activity” page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page)

I'd love to subscribe to a feed that detailed my activity: my questions asked, answers given, and comments made, and responses to my questions, answers, and comments.

Having played with dynamic RSS feeds, I know this is possible, but if it's enabled now, I certainly cannot find it.

Comment: Do you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/610217

Comment: Note [Jeff's statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed/104673#104673): *we are moving away from RSS to more email and web-based solutions to some of these things these days -- like newsletter subscriptions and tag subscriptions.* and see the nice Stack2RSS in that same post.

Comment: Jeff is moving __away__ from RSS and __towards__ e-mail? That answer is totally Photoshopped.

Comment: Well that's annoying... I don't want that in my inbox, but it's nice to see it in my reader.

Comment: Annoying? Did you read about Stack2RSS? Does everything you want, and then some more, I think!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the bottom right of a user's profile there is a link.

The tool tip reads

"feed of the 30 latest questions, answers, and comments from this user"

[image]

Comment: And anyone's responses through `/feeds/user/<userid>/responses`, but it seems the link for that has gone missing in the new user page? (It [used to be shown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/rss-feed-for-my-recent-activity-page/94037#94037) on one's own profile only, but it works for any user.)

Comment: Hah!  I was looking on the activity tab; it seemed like that's where it should be.  Yes indeed, this is great, thanks.