# How do I disable email notifications for one specific question of mine?

Tags: support, questions, notifications, email-notification

I posted a question to Stack Exchange several years ago ([this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1241154/debug-log-file-is-being-created-in-a-few-windows-folders-possibly-from-chrome/1599493#1599493)).  Users continue to read this question and post answers/comments.  When that occurs, I receive an email notification.  How can I disable those email notifications for this question only?

Comment: Fairly certain that is not possible. Since you provided an answer to your own question you can choose your answer as the correct answer, that usually provides some discouragement to people who would provide another answer; unless it's clearly *better* - then maybe you would want to see it. --- An alternative (poor) solution is to unsubscribe from email and [get an RSS feed of your recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/666/282094), of course that misses most of your Q&As; only recent activity is fed. --- Third choice: Add the Feature Request tag, and ask for this.

Comment: You could flag it and ask for it to be disassociated from your account. There are other consequences to that though i.e. you won't get rep from any votes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently there is no way to unsubscribe from email updates from a single question of yourself. If you think that would be a usefull feature to have for the entire network you can consider posting a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for that. Before doing so have a look at [How do I write a good feature request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258136/how-do-i-write-a-good-feature-request)

There are however a few things you could do to minimize or stop emails completely.

- **Change the frequency with which you receive emails.** This can be done from the [email preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) tab on your profile. You can choose between: Weekly, Daily, every 3 hours, or no emails.
  [image]
- **Ask to be dissasociated from that particular post.** This will result in you no longer getting emails about this post, but also has other consequences. Amongst other all related reputation changes will be reverted. *If the post was upvoted you will lose rep*. For more information see [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa).
- **Ask for the post to be protected.** If there are frequent low quality answers, mostly from low rep users, it can be worthwile to have the question protected. A protected question can only be answered by users that *gained 10 reputation on the specific site*, SuperUser in this case. The association bonus does not count. To do this flag for moderator attention and state your case in the flag dialogue box. For more info see [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-or-highly-active-question).